# Menu fixed on single page - change color

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to create a menu for a single page website with link to div from page.
The menu look like this:

```
<li><a href="#home-link" title="Home">Home</a></li>
...
<div id="home-link"></div>
```

I want to change color of link from menu when i am in area of home-link div. How is possible to make that thing?

Thanks for answers and for your help.

Have a nice day.

Comment: What does "when i am in area of home-link div" mean?

Comment: Do you mean like whenever you go to `site.whatevs.biz/#home-link`?  Or do you mean changing the actual anchor color?

Comment: Diodeus, something like here graffitifoods.ro . look at the menu,  please and scroll the page

Comment: sooo, u want when u hovering the "div" tag "home-link" the color of the "a" tag should change?

Answer (score 1):

You will need JavaScript for this if the link element is not a child of `#home-link`.

Something like this:

```
$('#home-link').on('hover', function () {
    $('li a').css('color', '#bada55');
});
```

This assumes you are using jQuery, but similar approach with other frameworks would work as well.

Comment: @impelo what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If I assume from the question that if you are hovering on `#home-link` and color of `anchor` should change, then

```
$('#home-link').hover(function () {
    $('li a').css('color', 'red');
});
```

or if I assume that if the `id` is present in your page and you want to change the color of the `anchor` then

```
if($('#home-link').length){
    $('li a').css('color', 'red');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found myself with (what I believe is) the same question: how can I change which navigation link is highlighted to reflect the area I've scrolled to, whether I get there by using the link or just by scrolling down the page?

[Here's a page with a very helpful tutorial.](http://callmenick.com/2013/04/22/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation/)

The theory:

> We create an array of all our nav a href’s. We then use some calculations using the scroll function. We find the section id, calculate it’s height, see if it’s greater or less than the value from the window top, and if the window falls in between, we add a class nav-active to the list item in question. We create a conditional also, because if the top of a section is not reached and the page can’t scroll anymore, we want to highlight this section.

And the relevant jQuery code:

```
/**
 * This part handles the highlighting functionality.
 * We use the scroll functionality again, some array creation and 
 * manipulation, class adding and class removing, and conditional testing
 */
var aChildren = $("nav li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
    var aChild = aChildren[i];
    var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
    aArray.push(ahref);
} // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
    var docHeight = $(document).height();

    for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
        var theID = aArray[i];
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
        var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
        if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
            $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
        } else {
            $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
        }
    }

    if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
        if (!$("nav li:last-child a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
            var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
            $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
            $("nav li:last-child a").addClass("nav-active");
        }
    }
});
```